# How to give user input in python3

Tags: python, list, input, defined

```
n=input("enter the no:")
check(test_list,n)

def check(test_list,n):
    for i in test_list:
        if(i==n):
             print("yes in a list")
             continue
        else:
            continue
```

I had written the simple code to check if a no. exists in a list or not, but while taking user input I"m not getting any results after providing input value n.

Why is so?

Comment: what is `test_list`? Presumably your mistake is assuming that `1 == "1"` which is not `True`.

Comment: "input" always returns a string. If you want a number you must convert the string.

Comment: @luk2302 test_list=[1, 6, 3, 5, 3, 4] which I"m providing and checking my input no. if in this list or not

Answer (score 1):

In your code the first line should be corrected as `n=int(input("enter the no:"))`.

In `python` it takes the `inputs` as `strings`. Think if you are giving the `input` as 3. Then the variable `n` stores the value "3"( not the value 3 ). You should need to know  `3 == "3"` is `False`.

Therefore, when you are taking the `input` you should convert that string `input` to the `int`. To do that we use `int()` method. The `int()` method converts the specified value into an integer number

n=int(input("enter the no:"))
check(test_list,n)

```
def check(test_list,n):
    for i in test_list:
        if(i==n):
             print("yes in a list")
             continue
        else:
            continue
```

Answer (score 0):

You were not getting any results because the input() function always returns a string. For this reason, we need to convert it to an Integer before passing it on into the function, and I did with `n=int(input())`.

```
n=int(input("enter the no:"))

def check(test_list,n):
    for i in test_list:
        if(i==n):
             print("yes in a list")
             continue
        else:
            continue

check((1,2,3),n)
```